# Checking image resolution before uploading to remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a function to upload image to remote server. Upload function working fine, but once I add that upload function code block inside size validation block, it is not working.
here is the html

```
  <p>
<input type="file" id="BtnBrowseHidden" name="files" style="display: none;" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().SelectFile(event)" />                                         
                                     <label class="btn bluebg " for="BtnBrowseHidden" id="LblBrowse" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                                  Update Image
             
                                     </label>                       
                    </p>
```

here is the validation code

```
$scope.SelectFile = function (e) {       
        var ext = e.target.files[0].name.split('.').pop();
        var popupImage = angular.element(document.querySelector('#popup__UpdateImpage'));
        popupImage.removeClass('hide');
        popupImage.addClass('hide');
        if (ext == 'png' || ext == 'gif' || ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'jpeg') {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = e.target.result;
                img.onload = function () {
                    if (img.height > 150 && img.width > 150) {
                        $scope.PreviewImage = e.target.result;
                        var payload = new FormData();
                        payload.append("file", e.target.files[0]);
                        var res = mainServices.uploadUserImage(payload);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("File size doesn't support");
                    }
                }
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
           
            //var payload = new FormData();
            //payload.append("file", e.target.files[0]);
            //var res = mainServices.uploadUserImage(payload);
            //res.then(function (response) {
            //    //alert("uploaded");
            //    var s = "uploaded";
            //});
        }
```

If I add that code block outside the validation block, it works fine. but how can I restrict uploading only if the size is above that size?
There is no other button for validation, I actually needs this to be done once they select the file, it should validate and change the image and update the remote server. Is there any way I can achieve this ? All codes I have found is always validating then on another button click it updates to the server.

Comment: Why not just have a button that lets the user upload the image once they've seen the preview and the validation has occurred? Just don't enable the button unless `$scope.PreviewImage` is set. When they click it, read the file from the `input` again.

Comment: did You tried to assign the `img.src` *after* the `img.onload` function expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the FileReader, you can set the image's source via `window.URL.createObjectURL`.

I am not sure why your code does not work, but I refactored and this solution works:
https://jsfiddle.net/1pL4rqe2/

I also added a directive to use the file input with `ng-change` ;)
That's the Angular way!

Answer (score 0):

you should do that validation when the image file is selected.

I'm assuming you have a "file" element:

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
let imgfile = new Image()
imgfile.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
imgfile.onload = () => {
   imgWidth = imgfile.width;
   imgHeight = imgfile.height;
}
});
```

After this you'll have imgWidth and imgHeight variables so you can validate them as you please, disabling the upload button for example if the image size doesn't fit your needs etc.

Comment: it could also be written in pure javascript, but I thought you were using JQuery based on your code.

Comment: Not my question or my code, but my apologies, the OP added the [jquery] tag when I wasn't looking :).

Comment: there is no other button for validation, I actually needs this to be done once they select the file, it should validate and change the image and update the remote server. Is there any way I can achieve this ? All codes I have found is always validating then on another button click it updates to the server.

Comment: Submitting an image that passes your validation is as simple as `if (valid) { e.target.form.submit() }`. Resampling the image client-side doesn't seem ideal to me, but if you must, you could [render it into a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) at the size you need and [extract it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) from there as an image.

Comment: @rayhatfield actually that is not resampling. actually what I want is when they select a file, it should check the size of the file and if size is too small, then don't save to server, if file size is big enough then save to server. Any idea how can I achieve this?